# Sort 'recently popular' posts from a table where popularity is decided by a count from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting

I am creating an article aggregator. The articles can be upvoted by the users who are signed in.
2 relevant tables to this question are

**News**

```
nid    ntitle                     nurl              ndatetime

 16    Apple                       abc.com/apple    2017-07-23 16:16:35   
 17     XYZ                        forbes.com/xyz   2017-07-23 17:16:35   
 18     ABC                        tc.com/abc       2017-07-24 18:16:35
```

**upvotes**

```
upvoteid   nid    userid
  1         16      23
  2         16      107
  3         18      2045
```

**Desired output**

```
18 
16
17
```

How do i write an sql statement that will sort the recently popular posts from the news table. By popular i mean most upvoted.

Each row containing the **nid** in the upvote table  is counted as an upvote for the news article.The upvote count for **nid** 16 would be 2 in the above case. So it is placed above news with id 17 which has an upvote count of 0. But 18 is sorted above 16 as it is from a later date even though it has an upvote count of only 1.

Note that news with nid 17 is of a later time than 16 but still goes below 16 as they are of the same date and sorting for the same day is based on upvote count.

The end result should be the posts of today sorted on total number of upvotes, followed by posts of yesterday sorted by most upvotes and so on.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: can you share the schema of both the tables and elaborate on your questions as its very unclear what you are looking for?

Comment: @JRG i made some edits take a look at it now

Comment: You better show some efforts first, and provide us with what have you tried already. If, by doing so, you failed to get your desired results, then we can all help you better. Plus, it's better to show a sample of desired output as well.

Comment: @PaulKaram   I added a sample output.

Comment: And Have you tried anything that gave you a wrong result other than intended?

Comment: One more note: `But 18 is sorted above 17`, do you actually mean above 16? Since the desired output shows that.

Comment: @PaulKaram yes i meant 16 i corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order posts by day and votes for that post on that day then even `upvotes` table need to have datetime.

Anyways, with given data and expected results here is the query.

```
SELECT n.nid, n.ntitle, n.nurl, DATE(n.ndatetime) as dateonly, up.votes
FROM news n, (SELECT nid, COUNT(*) AS votes
               FROM upvotes
               GROUP BY nid) AS up
WHERE n.nid = up.nid
ORDER BY dateonly DESC, up.votes DESC
```

Sample Run
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ORDER BY n.dateonly` ? Adding the table alias `n`

Comment: nope, it gives error if i use `n.dateonly`, hence i used `dateonly` without prefixing it with alias `n`

Comment: Oh okay, my bad then. Maybe this is because you gave it an alias as well. If it was a column name it would be different. Not totally sure.