# Sort div based on value in database in PHP

Tags: php, database

So I have a website where I have companies listed. I have a category section where I put some categories who I may think are popular, you can see a picture of it below. When people are searching for a company on the website or click one of these categories, that data is saved in a database. So the search history is saved. What I am trying to achieve is to know which category is more popular based on the values that are saved in the database and sort the category section. For example if restaurants is more popular in the database it should come first in the category section. I searched for this on google but I couldn’t find an answer. How can I achieve this in PHP?

[image]

Comment: First, make sure bots don’t get recorded for clicking those. You can use a `rel` attribute if they are links, but it might be better to make those form buttons, or to use JS. Next, write the query literally for the “Hotels” version and get it working as you want. Then repeat with “Restaurants”. Then, hopefully you should be able to determine a pattern where you can inject a [`COUNT` sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45319738/231316).

Comment: Also, I personally don’t like or recommend having one page returning potentially two different result sets for two different people, unless the query is tailored to each specific person, which doesn’t appear to be the case here. If Person A gets sorted one way, Person B clicks something to change the weight, and then Person C, without doing anything, gets a different result than Person A, I think there’s no value and it could lead to confusion. Instead, I’d still record, but change your default manually, periodically.